# Can someone check if this “proof” is correct?

Tags: geodesic, noneuclidean-geometry

I posted about this a few weeks ago, but I am trying to determine if there is some point south of Seattle (along the same longitude) in the continental United States with a larger geodesic distance from Fort Lauderdale. The problem is written more formally in terms of spherical coordinates. Using a formula for geodesic distance I found online (images shown), I used Desmos to plot the geodesic distance as a function of the longitude of the point near Seattle. The distance seems to oscillate when this angle is varied, but can someone check this for accuracy?

[image: Problem setup and assumptions]

[image: Desmos setup]

[image: Desmos graph]

[image: First formula from source]

[image: Final formula from source]

[Source](https://www.math.ksu.edu/%7Edbski/writings/haversine.pdf)

[Previous thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4549340/how-does-earth-s-curvature-affect-flight-times)

Comment: "...south of Seattle (along the same latitude)..." doesn't make sense. Do you mean "... (along the same *longitude*)..."?

Comment: Yes, I just edited the questions. Do you have any thoughts on the accuracy of the claim?